# How to edit user password in Rails with custom Devise controller? :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I tried to let the user from `http://localhost:3000/account/password` edit their passwords.

But I get this in the Rails log:

> Started GET "/users/password/edit" for ::1 at 2017-03-30 10:10:32 +0800
>
> Processing by Users::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
>
> User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
>
> Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

Here is something that I tried.

`rails g devise:controllers users`

`rails g devise:views users`

#### Routes

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  registrations: 'users/registrations',
  sessions: 'users/sessions',
  passwords: 'users/passwords',
  confirmations: 'users/confirmations'
}

devise_scope :user do
  get 'sign_up', to: 'users/registrations#new'
  get 'sign_in', to: 'users/sessions#new'
  delete 'sign_out', to: 'users/sessions#destroy'
  get 'account/users', to: 'users/registrations#edit'
  get 'account/password', to: 'users/passwords#edit'
end
```

#### Controller

*app/controllers/users/passwords_controller.rb*

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

  def edit
    # super
    @user = current_user
  end


def update
# super
@user = User.find(current_user.id)

if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
  bypass_sign_in(@user)
  redirect_to account_users_path, notice: "恭喜，密码更改成功。"
else
  render :edit
end

end

protected

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
end

end
```

#### Views

*app/views/users/passwords/edit.html.erb*

```
<%= link_to "Edit Password", account_password_path %>
```

> Any help will be welcome.

Comment: @Ren Thank you for editing my English.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your contoller

```
prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :edit, :update]
```

if you are using latest version of rails the use:

```
prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [ :edit, :update]
```

Comment: It looks like doesn't working. I puth the code in `app/controllers/users/passwords_controller.rb`

Comment: Yes, the same error. I use pundit for the Authorization. I'm not sure whether `after_action :verify_authorized, unless: :devise_controller?`  in the `application_controller.rb` .  But the error still there even remove the code.